# Turkish characters in python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, turkish

I am playing around with the Twitter API, but I have several questions regarding the encoding of Turkish characters. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
# -*- coding: cp1254 -*-
import sys
import csv
import tweepy
import locale
import string
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "Turkish")

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

f=open("tweets.csv", "wb")
for q in [list of search queries]:

     a=[tweet.text.encode("utf-8") for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q, result_type="recent", include_entities=True, lang="tr").items(20)]
     wr=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
     wr.writerow(q)
```

Basically, what I'm doing is running the search api by iterating through a list of search queries and then writing the tweets into an excel file. However, no matter what I do, the tweets are written by replacing regular Turkish characters with other substitutes. I've tried several things (setting the locale, adding the .encode("utf-8") part, etc.), but I still don't know how to fix it.

Here is what I am talking about:

> what is written: DÃ¼n akÅŸam Ãœlker Arena
>
> what I want it to write: Dün akşam Ülker Arena

What I don't understand is that ü, Ü and ş are all in the local letters when I set the locale to Turkish, but Python substitutes these letters.

Comment: Are you viewing the csv file to see what is written? I think you would need a utf supported file viewer to see the proper Turkish characters.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Excel to view the csv file. I just manually input Turkish characters into Excel and then saved it as a csv file. When I opened it again, the "ü" character remained but the "ş" character had been replaced by a "?". Since "ü" is maintained when I do it manually, shouldn't that be the case when Python does it as well?

Comment: I had faced a similar problem once, but didn't bother solving it. Try reading it using a python program that decodes the text from the file and shows the output to a display box or something. Keep this in mind that the command prompt and a lot of other consoles cannot output unicode characters. Many IDE's can do it. I think Excel does have a problem showing utf characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I duplicated your code on my system (Windows 7, with Office 2010) and I got it working.  I used your code but I simplified the search query as follows:

```
search_results = api.search(q="canan1405", count=10)
for tweet in search_results:
    print tweet.text.encode('utf-8')
```

I pulled tweets from the 'canan1405' user as they contained Turkish characters. (Hope she doesn't mind!)

I simply redirected the output of my script to a file, as follows:

> python so_24038317.py > tweets.csv

At this point, the tweets.csv file contains Unicode characters encoded as UTF-8.  If I double-click on the file as you did, the default Excel display shows garbage characters much like in your case:

[image]

**Instead of double-clicking on the csv file, use the following steps to import the file:**

1. Start Excel.
2. Click the "Data" tab on the ribbon.
3. Click the "From Text" icon in the "Get External Data".
4. Locate the CSV file and click the "Import" button.
5. A wizard will be displayed.  In my case, it came up with the correct guess for the file contents (see the "File origin:" drop-down):

[image]

You can complete the rest of the steps for the wizard but they are optional.  The file displayed correctly:

[image]

As far as I can tell, it contains (and correctly displays) the following Turkish characters:

`ş, Ğ, İ, ğ, ı, ç`

Note that the character immediately after the string "Oyy şirin kedi" is an emoticon, not a valid UTF-8 character.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

use `iso-8859-9` or `iso-8859` encode to have turkish characters.

**EDIT :**
if you want utf8 encoding absolutly, decode and encode after
You can do this `myString.decode('iso-8859-9').encode('utf8')`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried the following: '(a=[tweet.text.decode(iso-8859-9).encode("utf-8") for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q, result_type="recent", include_entities=True, lang="tr").items(20)])' but I got an error saying _(UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u015e' in position 23: ordinal not in range(128))_. How may I fix this?

Comment: try to only decode, I think some turkish letters can't be encoded..
`myString.decode('iso-8859-9')`

Comment: you can use unicode function too : 

`unicode(s, 'utf-8')`

Comment: I read my file with this encoding and my Turkish character problem was solved. Example: Dataset(root.filename,"r",encoding='iso-8859-9')

Answer (score 2):

Try to give encoding when opening the file :

```
open('csvfilename.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```